# Spatial index on generated (virtual/stored) column?

Tags: mysql, laravel, spatial-index, generated-columns

I have a generated (`storedAs`) column in my Laravel database that takes two `decimal` columns `lat` and `lng` and returns a `point` geospatial type.   I'm using a generated column so as to avoid a scenario where the decimal lat/lng columns somehow get updated and the spatial latlng column doesn't (or vice versa).

I'd like to also index this column so as to perform speedy lookups, but running into a slight hitch. 
 I'm using the Laravel migration builder to generate the table schema.  Although the source columns are not nullable and default to `0`, it won't run if I also add a spatial index, citing all parts must be not null.  I'm assuming that "all parts" refers to just the `latlng` column.

The migration below uses the `spatialIndex()` method from [Grimzy's Laravel MySQL Spatial extension](https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial), but I don't think that's the issue, as the standard Laravel `Blueprint` class also returns the same result.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->decimal('lat', 8, 6)->default(0);
        $table->decimal('lng', 9, 6)->default(0);
        $table->point('latlng')->storedAs('POINT(lat, lng)');
        $table->spatialIndex('latlng');
    });
}
```

Upon migration:

```php
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1252 All parts of a SPATIAL index must be NOT NULL (SQL: alter table `locations` add spatial `locations_latlng_spatial`(`latlng`))
```

My only guess is that MySQL doesn't support spatial indexes on generated columns.  Or am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE: seems I'm using MariaDB and not MySQL, which doesn't currently support them.

Comment: [seems not supported](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07dbdc0055bfee6e6397957230276703)

Comment: @danblack [looks supported to me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b1a9855875db69ca12b25f72224d0fa)?

Comment: quite right - just need to make `latng` defined `STORED NOT NULL` in larvel.

Comment: @danblack actually that site made me remember I'm running MariaDB 10.2.  doesn't seem supported now...  thanks!

Comment: Seems unfixed in 10.5.0 still too. [MDEV-10964](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10964) and [MDEV-7687](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7687) would be worthy of your votes.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for MariaDB is to use triggers.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `geoms` (
    `lat` DECIMAL(20,6) NOT NULL,
    `lng` DECIMAL(20,6) NOT NULL,
    `latlng` POINT NOT NULL,
    SPATIAL INDEX `latlng` (`latlng`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Insert trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `geoms_before_insert`
BEFORE INSERT ON `geoms`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    set NEW.latlng = POINT(NEW.lat, NEW.lng);
END
```

Update trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `geoms_before_update`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `geoms`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.latlng = POINT(NEW.lat, NEW.lng);
END
```

A drawback with this method is once you changed how the value of the "virtual column" is derived, you would have to re-render all existing data manually.